# get points and cells from CGAL Mesh_complex_3_in_triangulation_3

Tags: c++, cgal

To retrieve the points and cells from a CGAL [Mesh_complex_3_in_triangulation_3 object](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Mesh_3/classCGAL_1_1Mesh__complex__3__in__triangulation__3.html#a1e69cf04e3d2956c2f56500a5d2eb1a0), I usually write the mesh to a medit file,

```cpp
std::ofstream medit_file(outfile);
c3t3.output_to_medit(medit_file);
medit_file.close();
```

and read parse that afterwards. There has to be a better way. Any hints?

Comment: A better way in order to do what?  You have the full API of the Complex_3_in_triangulation_3 and of Triangulation_3 to explore the c3t3 object.

Comment: In fact I think I understand your problem.  You have to click on  Is Model of: MeshComplexWithFeatures_3InTriangulation_3.
In CGAL we document the API most often only in the concept.